# How can i access object properties of another class in kivy without getting AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'

Tags: python, kivy

Hi i was trying to access the property of an object from a different class using self.ids.. but i get this annoying error  **AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'** 
Here is my Code when i click the "Button for boys" i get the error

.py file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class Get_People(BoxLayout):
      root_lbl=ObjectProperty()

class Get_Boys(BoxLayout):
     label_b=ObjectProperty()

     def show(self):
          self.ids. root_lbl.text='i am called'


class lstApp(App):
   def build(self):
        self.load_kv('dates_test.kv')
        return Get_People()

if __name__=='__main__':
      lstApp().run()
```

here is the .Kv  file

```
<Get_People>:
      root_lbl: root_lbl
      orientation: 'vertical'

      Button:
          name: root_btn
          id: root_btn
          text: "I am Root Button"
       Label:
          id: root_lbl
          text: "I am Root Label"
       Get_Boys:

<Get_Boys>:
    label_b: label_b
    Button:
        id: button_b
        text: "Button for boys"
        on_press: root.show()

    Label:
        id: label_b
        text: "Label for boys"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we observe we see that the children of `Get_Boys` are `button_b` and `label_b` so those are the elements that can be accessed through `ids`. But if we look in `Get_People`, `Get_Boys` is a child so you can access `Get_People` through the `parent` method, and then access through `root_lbl`:

```
class Get_Boys(BoxLayout):
     label_b=ObjectProperty()

     def show(self):
        self.parent.root_lbl.text='i am called'
```

Comment: So glad it worked like magic thanks and is there any place i can learn about that in advance